# How to solve the system of PDEs defining Killing vectors

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, integrable-systems

Recently I came across the following problem. Here's the setting:

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $\nabla$ the Levi-Civita connection, and $U$ a coordinate neighbourhood with coordinates $\{x^i\}$. $X = X^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ is a vector field. We denote by $\nabla_i$ the derivative $\nabla_\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$. Denote also $X^i_j := \nabla_j X^i$. Consider $\{ X^i, X^j_k\}$ to be unknown functions and show that the system $\begin{align} \nabla_i X^j &= X_i^j \\ \nabla_k X_i^j &= -R_{pki}^j X^p \end{align}$ with conditions $X_{ij} = -X_{ji}$, where $X_{ij} = X_i^kg_{kj}$, is completely integrable iff $M^n$ is of constant curvature. In this case the solution depends on $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ arbitrary constants.

The vectors in the solution space would be the Killing vector fields. The part with the number of constants is clear, but I couldn't acquire the curvature condition, no matter how I tried to attack it. Applying Frobenius' theorem didn't do the job for me, so I suppose I am making a mistake somewhere, be it logical, or computational. The problem is taken from Kentaro Yano's book *"Integral Formulas in Riemannian Geometry", Marcel Dekker Inc., NY, 1970*, p.35, Problem 19. Similar problems (21, 23, 25) follow, concerning different infinitesimal transformations. According to the convention of the book, the Riemannian curvature tensor is defined as $R_{ijk}^l \frac{\partial}{\partial x^l}= R(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j})\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$

Comment: You probably copied your equation wrong: for the equation with Riemann, did you want the final factor to be $X^p$ instead? Also, the way the question is written is strange: if you assume $X_{ij} = - X_{ji}$, then by definition the deformation tensor for $X$ vanishes, which implies that $X$ is Killing. When that happens the equation on $\nabla_k X^j_i$ is simply Jacobi's equation for Killing vector fields. In other words, the assumption that $X_{ij} = -X_{ji}$ implies the rest of the system, and I can't imagine why the exercise is formulated that way.

Comment: You are right about the index, but this was a typo only in the post (I edited it). Otherwise, the system is obviously trivial once we know that $X$ is Killing. I assume the idea is to first arrive at the curvature condition to illustrate what the extreme case is, and apply the symmetry $X_{ij} = - X_{ji}$ afterwards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The system of PDEs in the original post actually defines a connection $D$ on the bundle $\mathcal{E} = TM \oplus \mathfrak{so}(TM)$, by
$$ D_X \begin{pmatrix} Y \\ A \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \nabla_X Y + A(X)\\ \nabla_X A - R(X,Y) \end{pmatrix} $$
for all vector fields $X,Y$ and field $A$ of skewsymmetric endomorphisms of $TM$.  Killing vectors are in bijective correspondence with $D$-parallel sections of $\mathcal{E}$, a result due to Kostant and rediscovered by Geroch, who coined the term *Killing transport*.

Complete integrability is simply the flatness of $D$.  The curvature of $D$ is not difficult to calculate and one finds that $D$ is flat if and only if $R(X,Y)Z = \lambda \left( g(Y,Z)X - g(X,Z)Y \right)$, for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.  This is precisely the statement that the metric has constant sectional curvature.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to use the same result, but couldn't formulate it as cleanly, and got lost somewhere in the index notation.

Comment: I believe it should be $-A(X)$ instead of $A(Y)$ in the first row. I ran the computations and the result followed.

Comment: @StefanVasilev It's supposed to be $A(X)$, but the sign is correct.  For a Killing vector $Y$, $A = - \nabla Y$.  My conventions for Riemann follow Besse.