# Geometric obstruction for local existance of Killing fields

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a pseudo-Riemannian manifold and $\nabla$ its Levi-Civita connection. If one defines the connection $\overline{\nabla}$ in $TM\oplus {\rm End}(TM)$ by $$\overline{\nabla}_X(Y,F) = (\nabla_XY- F(X), \nabla_XF - R(X,Y)),$$then for any Killing field $\xi$ on $M$, we have that $(\xi, \nabla\xi)$ is a $\overline{\nabla}$-parallel section of $TM\oplus {\rm End}(TM)$, and in particular this gives a proof that if $M$ is connected, then a Killing field is determined by its $1$-jet at any point (this is actually an exercise in Moroianu's *Lectures in Kähler Geometry*).

My question is not about this. Flatness of $\overline{\nabla}$ would imply that given any $x \in M$ and $v \in T_pM$, there is a $\overline{\nabla}$-parallel section in a neighborhood of $x$ that realizes $v$. Motivated by that, I would like to compute the curvature $\overline{R}(X,Y)(Z,F)$. It has two components. The vector component vanishes (by a straightforward application of Bianchi's identity), while I get $$\begin{align*}
    & R(X,Y)F - \nabla_{X}R(Y,Z) + \nabla_{Y}R(X,Z) - R(X,\nabla_{Y}Z) \\ &\hspace{3cm}  + R(Y,\nabla_{X}Z) + R(X,F(Y)) - R(Y,F(X)) + R([X,Y],Z)
  \end{align*}$$for the endomorphism component.

So:

- Does the converse hold? Is it true that $\overline{\nabla}$-parallel sections define Killing fields? Or in other words, does $\nabla_X(\nabla\xi) = R(X,\xi)$ imply that $\xi$ is Killing?
- Is there an efficient way to simplify the endomorphism component of $\overline{R}(X,Y)(Z,F)$? A lot of these terms seem to be somewhat distinct in nature. General references are also welcome.

Comment: Haven't checked the details, but I think the answer to your first question is negative. Consider the standard flat Euclidean (or Minkowski) space (signature doesn't matter). Let $\xi = (x^1) \partial_{x^1}$. This vector field is not Killing, but $\nabla \nabla \xi \equiv 0 = R(\cdot, \xi)$.

Comment: Shoot. You're right, assume that $n=1$ for concreteness and do $\nabla(x\partial_x) = \nabla x\otimes \partial_x + x\otimes \nabla\partial_x = {\rm d}x\otimes \partial_x$. Then $$\nabla\nabla(x\partial_x) = \nabla({\rm d}x\otimes \partial_x) = \nabla({\rm d}x)\otimes\partial_x + {\rm d}x\otimes \nabla\partial_x = 0+0=0.$$This seems to somehow contradict this answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261613/how-to-solve-the-system-of-pdes-defining-killing-vectors?rq=1) I found after posting, no? They don't have much details there.

Comment: Isn't the answer you quoted for a system? You need also that $D_XY = 0$ (in the notation of that answer), which (in your notation) requires there to exists some **antisymmetric automorphism** $A$ such that $A(X) = \nabla_X \xi$. This latter condition is the same as saying that $\nabla \xi^\flat$ is antisymmetric, or simply that Killing's equations are satisfied.